# unix command cut + grep to extract some detailed information

Tags: unix, grep, cut

I need to count the lines of a file that contains following information.

1. The first 2 characters have to be 21
2. The 54th character needs to be 0 or 6
3. The 57-58 character need to be greater then 49

I need this in a single command if possible.
I tried the following:

> cut -c 1-2,54 $filename|grep -e 210 -e 216

This gives me the first 2 conditions.
I don't know how to get also the 3rd condition to match.
If I do something like this:

> cut -c 1-2,54,57-58 $filename|grep -e 210 -e 216

Then I get also something like `22160` that matches the pattern, which is not correct.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Please, post some sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may reach your goal by using `awk`.

```
awk '(substr($0,1,2)==21 && (substr($0,54,1)==0 || substr($0,54,1)==6) && substr($0,57,2)>49 ){count=count+1} END{print count==""?0:count}' Your_file
```

Brief explanation,

`substr($0,s,l)`: extract the sub-string of `$0` start from `s` and which length is `l`